# Python audio analysis of data: mapping data to pitch, tempo and volume

Tags: python, audio

I am experimenting with an unusual way of analysing data; I want to generate audio from my data.

**[PseudoCode]**

```
data = fetch_data()

with open('soundfile.wav', 'w') as f:
    for elem in data:
        x, y, z = elem
        pitch, tempo, volume = map_to_sound_function(x, y, z)
        append_sound_to_file(f, pitch, tempo, volume)
```

How would I go about implementing the functions `map_to_sound_function()` and `append_sound_to_file()` ?

Comment: Does your data have a regular structure or regular patterns? if this is not the case i would imagine you would generate noise.

Comment: @churchwalk Yes, it's a hierarchical FSM that cycles back and forth between known states.